# Как правильно говорить, писать?

Tags: стилистика

"Корректировка схемы, технических условий", или "коррекция схемы, технических условий"?

Comment: Народ, выделяйте кавычками слова или предложения, о которых спрашиваете!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы выбрала первый вариант. "Коррекция" интуитивно просится там, где речь идет о человеке: "коррекция зрения", "коррекция речи".

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае КОРРЕКТИРОВКА.

***Корректиро́вка.*** Ж. 1. процесс действия по гл. корректировать 2. Результат такого действия; корректирование.
dic.academic.ru › *Толковый словарь Ефремовой*

***КОРРЕ́КЦИЯ***, и, мн. нет, ж. [нем. Korrektion, фр. correction < лат. corrēctio]. спец.Исправление.К. зрения (исправление недостатков зрения при помощи очков).
Яндекс.Словари › *Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2004*

***КОРРЕ́КЦИЯ***, коррекции, жен. (лат. correctio) (книжн.). 1. Исправление (спец.). Коррекция зрения (исправление недостатков зрения посредством очков; мед.). 2. То же, что коррекция зрения (мед.).
dic.academic.ru › *Толковый словарь Ушакова*

***Корре́кция***. Ж. Исправление, поправка.
dic.academic.ru › *Толковый словарь Ефремовой*